# Get response from other website

Tags: php, get

i want code to give me the response of form on another website and i get the response in the same page of the code for example

there is a field called
"put your email to reset your password"
""

my idea is this

```
$url = 'http://example.com/reset.php';
&email = a@a.com;

//now i want excute email in the form inside the url 

do $email in the form of this $url and give me the response
```

for example

your email doesn't exist

and sure i want all of this without going to the website above i just want to know what is the response of the form when i put email

i hope that you got my idea
and i'm sorry for my English.

Comment: The tool you're looking for is called `cURL`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: how i use it? i tried to understand it but icould not

Comment: "I could not understand" isn't really an answerable question.  What have you tried?  Start with simple examples (a quick Google search will find many) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  jQuery('#submit').click(function () {
    var email = jQuery('#email').val();

    jQuery.post('http://example.com/reset.php', {email: email}).done(function (result) {
      jQuery('#result').text(result.status);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="email" id="email"/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<div id-"result"></div>
```

http://example.com/reset.php:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];

if (is_valid($email)) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Your email is valid'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Your email is not valid'));
}

function is_valid($email) {
    // do something to validate the email (for ex. check match in database etc)
   // return true OR false
}
```